# Wrong drawer width

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am using a DrawerNavigator on my app. This is my code

On my app.js

```
<Provider store={store}>
            <RootContainer />
            </Provider>
```

on RootContainder

```
const AppDrawer = DrawerNavigator(
{
  Home: {
    path: '/',
    screen: WelcomeContainer,
  },
  Category: {
    path: '/list',
    screen: listContainer,
  },
},
{
  contentComponent: SideMenu,
  initialRouteName: 'Home',
  contentOptions: {
    activeTintColor: '#4edb6d',
  },
}
);
```

and I embed the drawer on my stackNavigato

```
const AppNavigator = StackNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: AppDrawer,
    navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
```

The problem is that in lanscape mode or on tablets the drawer uses about 80% from the screen size which is very big. The second problem is that the width is not being recalculated when the device orientation changes: If I start the app when the device is on landscape and then change the orientation to portrait, the drawer has a width higher than the devices width. Do you know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

**First** problem add `drawerWidth: (width you want)` to the DrawerNavigatorConfig.

**Second** problem i suggest the following solution:

- use react-native-orientation to listen to orientation change
- write a function (e.g calculateScreenWidth) that calculates the width 
  by using `Dimensions.get('window').width` and set it in state as `screenWidth` (or what ever you want)
- Call `calculateScreenWidth` every time orientationChanges using `_orientationDidChange` provided by react-native-orientation
- Finally, give `drawerWidth:this.state.screenWidth`.

Hope this helps.